# OkHttp + Picasso + Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, picasso, okhttp

The question is how to combine all these **3** libraries in one project?

- Make one OkHttpClient to be a background layer for both Picasso and Retrofit.
- How to make Priority changes like in Volley lib. (for pagination)?

Comment: "The question is how to combine all these 3 libraries in one project?" -- download the three JARs and their dependencies (e.g., GSON), or reference all three artifacts in your Gradle or Maven build. "Make one OkHttpClient to be a background layer for both Picasso and Retrofit." -- AFAIK, Retrofit and Picasso will use OkHttp automatically. "How to make Priority changes like in Volley lib. (for pagination)" -- please explain in greater detail what your problem is here, and how "priority changes" has anything to do with "pagination".

Comment: When using a retrofit I have to manually create an OkClient wich takes an OkHttpClient at the constructor. But I don't know whether these two libraries gonna use the same OkHttpClient as a background whether I don't create my own OkHttpClient for Picasso.

What about pagination and priority:
When you scrolling the list of items the and close to the end of page, N more items should be downloaded and in volley the request for downloading new items takes the highest priority when images got low. So when it's time to load new items into the list they will be downloaded immediatly

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient)).build();
OkHttpDownloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient);
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this).downloader(downloader).build();
```

I do not think it's possible to have priorities with the current version of Retrofit.

Comment: How to use two different cache directories for retrofit and Picasso? Is there a way other than using two instances of OkHttpClient?

Answer (score 8):

For OkHttpClient 3.0 and Retrofit 2.0 it is:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cache(cache) // optional for adding cache
    .networkInterceptors().add(loggingInterceptor) // optional for adding an interceptor
    .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://api.yourdomain.com/v1/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build();

Picasso picasso = Picasso.Builder(context)
    .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
    .build();
```

Prioritization has been moved down the stack model to the http client, and there is an issue being studied: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1361

Comment: Don't forget to add `compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'` to a build.gradle.