# Picasso: Received response with 0 content-length header FROM DISK

Tags: android, picasso

This may be a bug in Picasso, but I wanted to post to StackOverflow first.

I am getting the error "Received response with 0 content-length" when the responses are being read from the cache from disk. I can reproduce this error every time by

1) Run my app without OKHttp in classpath. Let pictures load

2) Add OkHttp into classpath, I get that error.

I added Picasso source to my project to investigate further. I found out that

1) Turning off caching `connection.setUseCaches(false);` will bypass the error (since it ignores the cache)

2) I found the switch in the Picasso source where it checks if OkHttp was available

`try {
   Class.forName("com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient");
   okHttpClient = true;
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {}`

and was able to reproduce the bug by hardcoding true, then false between runs.

I want to solve this problem so I can use OKHttp (and provide a viable upgrade for my current users) and all the benefits that come with it. I also have seen this "reading response with no content-length from cache" problem in other cases in my live environment. Once I get into the state with a bad response in cache, the pictures will never show up.

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to help you without the code that is raising the error, plus the stack trace of the exception itself. It wouldn't shock me if the Square team might even need a reproducible test case.

Answer (score 3):

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient)).build();
OkHttpDownloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient);
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this).downloader(downloader).build();
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23832172/2158970

Comment: This doesn't use the cache. It loads from network every time.